# Content Script loads on all pages of facebook, but does not work except on home page

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a chrome extension which works on Facebook. The extension puts a private like button beside the ordinary like button. I have made this extension for a client, and the purpose of this extension is to conduct private likes between the extension users. The extension populates the private like button when the user is logged in into the extension.

The **Private Like** button populates well on all pages of Facebook. i.e; on the home page, on every post of the group when you open one, on your profile. But it just works on the home page only and I don't know why. I thought the problem will be because of the URL in the content script matches. As I have provided `"http://www.facebook.com/*","https://www.facebook.com/*"`. And the Facebook group URL is `https://www.facebook.com/groups/thedigits...` so I have changed the matches to  `https://www.facebook.com/groups/*/` same I did for the profile. But still did not work for me.

**My Manifest**

```js
{
 "name":"Private Like",
 "description":"Privately like facebook users post through this extension !",
 "version":"1.0",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "icons":{"16":"icons/icon_liked.png","32":"icons/icon_liked.png","64":"icons/icon_liked.png","128":"icons/icon_liked.png"},
 "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": [
        "http://www.facebook.com/*",
        "https://www.facebook.com/*",
    ],
       "js": ["jquery.js", "document.js"]
     }
    ],
    "background":{
        "matches": [
        "http://www.facebook.com/*",
        "https://www.facebook.com/*"
  ],
     "scripts":["jquery.js","background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
     "http://www.facebook.com/*",
     "https://www.facebook.com/*",
     "http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/*"
    ],
 "browser_action":{"default_icon":"icons/icon_liked.png"}
}
```

> You can check the extension working , [install the simple file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Nu36NpXiu8SmE0ZkpHMVZWRjQ) and check that scripts.
>
> > I just need the private like button working on the profile and groups pages as well.
> >     It just sends a simple ajax request and return a value, and that value you can check on the login page console.

Comment: But still it loads the button on each page, it means its populating the button, but if the button is there why it only works on the home page, even when I go to a group or my profile page and then visit back to the home page still the like works on the home page

Comment: and when I reload the window, on the profile or groups page still the button doesn't work except on the home

Comment: As you can check I have used the interval, and after 2 seconds it populates the button @wOxxOm

Comment: Well, try debugging in devtools by setting breakpoints in the event listeners, step through the code, inspect variables and so on.

Comment: Is it working for you now? can you share your solution?

Comment: Yes @kalsky the setinterval() worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `setInterval()` method of javascript the function inside it will be called after a specific interval and each time it will go through the facebook posts and will check if the private like button is populated to it or not. The function inside the   `setInterval()` method will populate the button.

I have set the interval to 2000 ms or 2 seconds. Which call the function inside after two seconds and now it is populating the button everywhere.